# Powdered Milk - Chalav Yisroel

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk

I have a child with a milk allergy. He will be undergoing a "baked milk" food challenge shortly. For this I need to bake him muffins with powdered milk.

I have found several brands of kosher powdered milk, but so far, I couldn't find any that is chalav yisroel, and available for purchase in the USA. Does anyone here know of any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at http://www.kashrut.com/consumer/dairy/Cholov_Yisrael.pdf (which now that I discovered it, looks very useful in general), I searched for "powder". I got:

- Haddar 27090 Milk Powder

After reading the corrections towards the end I'm confused about these 3:

- Bluegrass Dairy & Food #21-208 BDF0032 SK Whole Milk Powder
- Bluegrass Dairy & Food #66-075 BDF0336 Sweet Cream Powder 56%
- Bluegrass Dairy & Food #66-075 BDF0337 Sweet Cream Powder 42%

Also saw over [here](http://chowhound.chow.com/topics/273997):

> Bakers choice has just re-released their cholov yisroel condensed milk. it will most likely say condensed cream or something to that effect as new regulations didn't allow them to write condensed milk. any typical kosher grocery should have it{it just came back out about 2 weeks ago} if you don't find it ask them to order it from their distributor

Also mentioned in the same place: Kosure brand

---

As for leniency (FYI): from [Star-K over here](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-issues-cholovYisroel.htm):

> **Powdered Milk** - There are some Torah scholars who permit the use of powdered milk which is made from regular milk since it is not in its original form when it comes into Jewish hands. Most people who are careful about Cholov Yisroel do not rely on this lenient ruling.

Comment: Neither Haddar nor Bluegrass are Cholov Yisroel. I had already emailed Baker's Choice, they don't sell to consumers and they cannot be found in any grocery I tried. Kosure I also heard about but couldn't find.

Comment: @Barry how do you know they're not cholov yisroel?

Comment: I checked again and it *is* chalav yisrael after all. Somehow I missed it the first time I read the label. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Barry, you should speak to your Rav about this.  There are a number of mitigating factors:

- That it is powdered (see yydl above)
- That it is for refuah
- The reason why your family keeps chalav Yisrael (not only that it may only be a chumra for you, but also whether your son is required to keep your chumra)
- The age of the child

Also, most who keep CY as a chumra are not concerned about the keilim.

Comment: I appreciate the information, but this doesn't address the question, which was whether Chalav Yisroel milk powder exists. If I cannot find any, then I will explore leniencies.

Answer (score 3):

Here are links where you can purchase Cholov Yisroel powdered milk.

https://www.rocklandkosher.com/c-682-Milk-Powder.aspx

http://www.kosheronweb.com/store/review/product/list/id/5772/

https://glattmart.rapidorders.com/order.php?todaySp=&itemDetailId=96582&todaySp=&referer=products.php?cId=21355&PHPSESSID=c74fbbdcaf515320497427373690d2ef

Comment: Is "Rockland Kosher Milk Powder" Chalav Yisroel? The third link you provided looks promising. I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Grr, GlattMart does't have it (notwithstanding the website).

Comment: The Rockland Kosher is Chalav Yisrael

Answer (score -3):

Rav Moshe Feinstein posseked that Milk inspected by the American government is considered Cholov Yisroel since their regulations and supervision is strong enough to prevent American milk providers from mixing in non-cow milk.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Note that not everyone agrees with _Rav Moshe_'s leniency, and that even among those who do are many who try to not rely on it (as _Rav Moshe_ himself suggested).